# ¿Se puede incluir proyecto Net Framework 4.0 en solucion con proyectos de Net Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, net, microsoft

Se puede incluir un proyecto que necesariamente tiene que estar en Net Framework 4.0 en una solucion que tiene todos sus proyectos en Net Framework 3.5 ?

El proyecto en NetFramework 4.0 implemnta SignalR y por eso no puede ser bajado de Framework.

Comment: Intentaste hacerlo y te dio algun problema? Deberias poder hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si. Se puede incluir. El framework de compilacion se configura para cada proyecto.

Solo tiene que tener en cuenta que al referenciar un proyecto (Proyecto Referenciado) desde otro proyecto (Proyecto que referencia) la version del Framework del proyecto que referencia debe ser superior a la del proyecto referenciado. En otras palabras el conjunto de operaciones del Framework del proyecto que referencia debe ser un superconjunto del conjunto de operaciones del proyecto referenciado.